# How to limit users to their own assets when deleting content

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I wrote a small application that contains the user base and the assets assigned to them.
Now, I'm trying to write a function which will delete record from databese only when user isn't assign to assets.

**Load assets**

```
$http.get("/ewidencja/dbs/assets.php").then(function (response) {
  $scope.aktywa = response.data.records;  
});
```

**Load users**

```
$http.get("/ewidencja/dbs/users.php").then(function (response) {
  $scope.pracownicy = response.data.records;
});
```

**Remove function**

```
$scope.usunUsera = function(s) {  
if (confirm("Na pewno?")) {
$http.post("/ewidencja/dbs/removeuser.php", {
  'id_pracownika': s
  }).then(function(response) {
    alert("Usunięto");
    }, function(error) {
      alert("Błąd! Dane nie dodane!");
      console.error(error);
    }); 
 } }
```

**I choose users from options:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h5>Usuń użytkownika</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select ng-model="idPracownika" class="form-control" ng-options="ludzie.idPracownik as ludzie.NazwaPracownika for ludzie in pracownicy"><option value="" selected="selected">Wybierz</option></select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="usunUsera(idPracownika)">Usuń użytkownika</button>
  </div>
```

**removeuser.php**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = $data->id_pracownika;
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM pracownicy WHERE id_pracownik='".$id."'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Usunięto poprawnie";
} else {
echo "Błąd: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

Now, i can delete users from DB even if they are assign to assets but I would like to protect this app against this.

Can You help me with this case? Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Your question is related to php and not directly related with angularjs. You need to ask how to limit your users to their own assets. You need to revise your question based on these terms.

Comment: Maybe you should explain *__how__ users are assigned to assets?* How is the *assignment* made, in the database? What code checks for an assignment?

Comment: In MysQL DB i have two tables: assets and users. In specific asset i put user ID. But i don't know how to write a function wich will be checking that assigment.

Comment: what you want to do is get the user that's logged in and check if the assets has the user id of the logged in user. But without knowing more about the project this is the most help people can give

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new query right before the delete query, with that one checking if the user has any assets.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets WHERE id_user = ?;
```

Then you can store that result in a counter and use it to restrict if the delete operation can be made or not

```
if(counter==0){
  console.log("No items were deleted");
 }else{
 DELETE FROM....
   }
```